# Dynamically referring to an array

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/sh -x

GRADES=(FIRST SECOND)
FIRST_GRADE=(JOHN MICHAEL)
SECOND_GRADE=(MARY SUSAN)

for grade in "${GRADES[@]}"
do
   echo $grade
   for name in "${$grade_GRADE[@]}"
   do
      echo "...$name"
   done
done
```

But I get `./miniPlay.sh: line 7: ${$grade_GRADES[@]}: bad substitution`

So basically I am trying to first go through `"${FIRST_GRADE[@]}"` and then `"${SECOND_GRADE[@]}"`

So the line:   `for name in "${$grade_GRADE[@]}"`
will be evaluated differently depending on what iteration of the `GRADES` array we are going through

Comment: use `#!/bin/bash` for bash scripts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a temporary variable you can use `${!...}` in bash:

```
#!/bin/sh -x

GRADES=(FIRST SECOND)
FIRST_GRADE=(JOHN MICHAEL)
SECOND_GRADE=(MARY SUSAN)

for grade in "${GRADES[@]}"
do
   temp=${grade}_GRADE[@]
   for name in ${!temp}
   do
      echo "...$name"
   done
done
```

Comment: Lovely... thanks Beni. Is there anywhere you know of that explains the use of the various syntax (i.e. (,$,",{ ,[@] etc), it would be good if I knew exactly what was going on

Comment: It all mentioned in `man bash`..  And then googling around to see if there is a better way

Answer (score 0):

You have almost got your script working. Here is another solution that uses `eval`.

```
#!/bin/sh -x

GRADES=(FIRST SECOND)
FIRST_GRADE=(JOHN MICHAEL)
SECOND_GRADE=(MARY SUSAN)

for grade in "${GRADES[@]}"
do
   echo $grade
   eval "data=\${${grade}_GRADE[@]}"
   for name in $data
   do
      echo "...$name"
   done
done
```

**Update:** as Glenn Jackman points in the comments this does not handle correctly array elements with embedded spaces like

```
       SECOND_GRADE=("MARY ANN" SUSAN)
```

To fix this Glenn suggests making `data` above an array and quoting the values in it

```
       eval "data=(\"\${${grade}_GRADE[@]}\")"
       for name in "${data[@]}";
```

Comment: To properly handle names with spaces, make "data" an array: `eval "$(printf 'data=("${%s_GRADE[@]}")' $grade)"; for name in "${data[@]}"; ...`

Comment: @glennjackman thank you for making this comment. Also you do not need an extra `printf` since you can escape the quotes in the string  submitted  to `eval`.